# Calling WCF service in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, azure-functions

Does anyone know how to configure a WCF service to be called from Azure Function?

Scenario:

- I have a azure functions project.
- I have a core project which consists of controllers and mappers.
- This core project has a connected service configured.
- I have configured the endpoint and binding that work from a test project.

But every time i call it from the functions i get:

> Could not find endpoint element with name 'ABC' and contract 'ABC' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.

Configuration for service:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TranslationBridgeWebServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="TranslationBridgeWebServiceSoap12" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
      <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressingAugust2004" writeEncoding="utf-8">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" allowInsecureTransport="false" />
      <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://abc/TranslationBridgeExternalService.asmx" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="TranslationBridgeWebServiceSoap12" contract="ABC" name="ABC" />
  <endpoint address="https://abc/TranslationBridgeExternalService.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TranslationBridgeWebServiceSoap" contract="ABC" name="ABC" />
</client>
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `web.config` file for Azure Function App (it will be ignored if you put it manually).

So you would have to create your WCF client by configuring it in code. Effectively, instantiate all the bindings, endpoints etc in the code. For each WCF class there's always a constructor to instantiate an entity with all the parameters without config files.

Comment: Wouldn't it be same as moving the call to a dependent project. This project has all the configuration, app.config, etc. and calling it in turn? Or am i missing something here. Thanks. :)

Comment: No, `app.config` won't be picked up either. Configuration is controlled by Functions runtime.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. will try that.

Comment: Another option is to do imperative (doing binding in codes such as new BasicHttpBinding/CustomBinding and so on) instead of config.   Looking at the binding above, it should not be hard to achieve.